# Can model declarations be forwarded?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing configuration dictionaries into my models. I need to access the forwarded declaration of model declared below the model im configuring right now. For example

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    TYPE_MODEL = {
        'type1': SecondModel,
        'type2': ThirdModel
    }

    some_field = models.CharField(
        choices=(
            ('type1', 'type 1 display'), 
            ('type2', 'type 2 display')
        )
    )

    def do_some_with_config(self):
        model = self.TYPE_MODEL.get(self.some_field)
        ... do something with model ...


class SecondModel(models.Model):
    ... its own fields ...


class ThirdModel(models.Model):
    ... its own fields ...
```

Is here any better approach to do this than moving the FirstModel below the ThirdModel or is it generally a good idea to have these dicts with configuration in the model?

Comment: Maybe you should have that as a foreignkey, and have another class as father of Second and Third.... or also, have one FK to Second, and another to Third, and have a pre_save signal to make sure that only one of those models are related

Comment: Actually i store the instances of the `SecondModel` and `ThirdModel` in the content type field in the `FirstModel`. I need to have model that can be easily configurable via configuration dictionaries I'm using without changing its structure and changing migrations.